# Как сделать удаление элементов объекта через lodash?

Tags: javascript, функции, lodash

К примеру, есть словарь

```
let object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };
```

И путь к удалению

```
let path = 'a[0].b.c';
```

Нужно сделать функцию типа

```
const deleteObj = (obj, path) => {}
```

чтобы результат на выводе был таким:

```
{ 'a': [{ 'b': {} }] }
```

Должно работать с любым уровнем вложенности

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете попробовать оба метода, однако это **небезопасно**.

Почему не стоит переводить строку в выражение описано [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5_eval_%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8!)

1:

```
let obj = {"a" : [ {b: {c: 3} } ] },

path = 'obj["a"][0].b',

exp = new Function('return ' + path); 
function convert(e) {
  return e();
};

function deleteProp (o, b) {
    for (let key in b) {
       delete b[key];
    }
}

deleteProp(obj, convert(exp));
```

2:

```
let obj = {"a" : [ {b: {c: 3} } ] },
path = eval('obj["a"][0].b');

function deleteProp (o, b) {
  for (let key in b) {
     delete b[key];
  }
}

deleteProp(obj, path);
```

Comment: Суть в том, что путь к удаляемому объекту находится в строке

Comment: @НиколайСычев обновил ответ

Answer (score 2):

Безопасный вариант с разбором пути:

```js
function deleteProp(obj, path) {
  if (!/^(\w+)(?:\[(\w+)\]|\.(\w+))*$/.test(path)) {
    throw "Invalid path!";
  }
  
  const parts = path.replace(/\[(\w+)\]/g, '.$1').split('.');
  const lastPart = parts.pop();
  let prop = obj;
  for (const part of parts) {
    prop = prop[part];
    
    if (prop === undefined) {
        throw "Path does not exist!";
    }
  }
  
  const deleted = prop[lastPart];
  delete prop[lastPart];
  return deleted;
}

const object = { 'a': [{ 'b': [5, { 'c': 3 }] }] };
const path = 'a[0].b[1].c';
const deleted = deleteProp(object, path);
console.log(deleted);
console.log(object);
```

Comment: ваша регулярка не работает, если будет вложенный массив внутри объекта `b`

Comment: нужно добавить доп условие, количество родителей в функцию и потом пройтись по ним

Comment: for (let i = 0; i < parentsCount; i++) {
        parts = parts.concat(lastPart.replace(/\[(\w+)\]*/, '.$1').split('.'));
        lastPart = parts.pop();
    }

Comment: @highpassion, я не претендую на 100% полноту (нужна ли она?), только хочу показать идею, ТС может использовать решение с любыми правками

Comment: @НиколайСычев, я лишь показываю идею, доводить до совершенства нету желания, вы можете основываясь на этой идее реализовать свое решение с нужной вам полнотой. И даже опубликовать его здесь отдельным ответом, это только приветствуется и, вероятно, кому-то пригодится

Comment: @АндрейNOP я сильно плаваю в регулярных выражениях, думал, может вы захотите усовершенствовать своё :)

Comment: @highpassion, первая или вторая регулярка? Можете подробнее описать? Пример привести, пока не понимаю

Comment: @АндрейNOP видимо, вторая, чтобы могла видеть массивы внутри объектов, хотя, догадываюсь, что  проверочную тоже придется поправить

Comment: @highpassion, ну в примере же уже есть массив внутри свойства `a`, вроде работает?

Comment: ТС: *Должно работать с любым уровнем вложенности*, внутри обьектов массива уже вложить массив c объектом не получится - `Uncaught Path does not exist!`

Comment: @highpassion, ага понял проблему, заменяется только первая пара квадратных скобок, в js есть дополнительные заморочки с флагами в регулярках, поправил ответ

Comment: @НиколайСычев, по идее дополнительный цикл с concat внутри не нужен, поправил регулярку чтобы менять все [], а не только первые

Comment: @АндрейNOP отличное решение )

Comment: Оказывается, при помощи lodash делается это очень просто

Answer (score 0):

```
const deleteSubProp = (data, path) => {
let newData = {...data},
    child,
    parents = path.replace(/\[(\w+)\]$/, '.$1').split('.');
child = parents.pop();
parents = parents.join('.');
delete _.get(newData, parents)[child];}
```

Делается при помощи lodash очень просто, как оказалось